# При вызове события подвисает UI

Tags: c#, listview, xaml, uwp, windows-10-mobile

C# UWP Windows 10.

Есть `ListView`, при клике по элементу вызывается `Event` в который передается нажатый объект, из App происходит переход на форму редактирования объекта. Проблема в том что после возврата на форму в этом `ListView` элемент отображается как нажатый, и в таком виде остается до перезапуска приложения. Подскажите как сделать что бы он нормально отображался?

UPD: Пример кода:

```
private void ListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    var item = (Tag)e.ClickedItem;
    TagBeginEditEvent.Invoke(item);
}
```

А в обработчике сигнала выполняется `Frame.NavigateTo`...

Comment: Эээ... Покажите пример с кодом. (И я правильно понял, что вы в обработчик передаёте `ListViewItem`?)

Comment: @VladD Обновил вопрос. Нет, передается само собой `DataContext` некий класс, хотя и не суть важно что именно передается, важно что навигация к окну редактирования осуществляется в обработчике сигнала и после редактирования значения элемента обновляются, но в UI сам элемент списка выглядит будто я на нем мышкой щелкнул и не отпускаю...